# how do i set the border radius of the lottieview in a react native page

Tags: react-native

the style of the view.  I've tried adding the height and width too

```
logo: {
marginRight: 40,
marginLeft: 40,
marginTop: 10,
backgroundColor: '#68a0cf',
borderRadius: 50,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: '#fff',
overflow: 'hidden'
```

},

For the Lottie view

```
 <LottieView
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../assets/church.json')}
            autoPlay
            loop
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `borderRadius` to the container of the lottie View and just give it an `overflow: 'hidden'`

```
<View style={styles.lottieContainer}>
    <LottieView
        loop
        autoPlay
        style={styles.lottieView}
        source={require('./scrolling-social-mdia.json')}/>
  </View>
```

these are the styles:

```
lottieContainer: {               
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 20,
},
lottieView: {
    width: '100%'
}
```